# How to model Global Constant in Scala using Enum?

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration of string coming from the result of a query into a database.

In other words, i'm querying a events from a database, and one of the attribute is event description, which should always belong to a set of well known string. E.g.

1. "PreferedLabelAdded"
2. "PreferedLabelChanged"

And so on.

I would like to model the possible string that comes from the database within Scala. I was thinking about using an Enum but I don't see how with what i have seen online.

Ultimately, what i would like to do is to compare the value of the attribute to one of this value to perform some tasks according to the type of event descriptions.

Alghough i could go and simply enter my magic string as such

```
if (eventDesc == "PreferedLabelAdded")
```

I find it bad, because one does not get one point of contact to change those string, but instead it get spread all over the code.

Maybe simply using an Object as such

```
Object EventDesc {

val PrefAdded = "PreferedLabelAdded""
val PrefChanged = "...." 

}
```

If anyone has some specific suggestion with that, that would be great.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the [scala.Enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) class to create your enumeration:

```
object EventDesc extends Enumeration {
    type EventDesc = Value
    val PreferedLabelAdded, PreferedLabelChanged, UNKNOWN = Value
}

val eventDesc = EventDesc.withName("PreferedLabelAdded")

if (eventDesc == EventDesc.PreferedLabelChanged) {
  Console.println(eventDesc)
}
```

You can also do pattern matching:

```
eventDesc match {
  case PreferedLabelAdded | PreferedLabelChanged       => handleEvent(context)
  case UNKNOWN                   => ignoreEvent(context)
  case _                          => // noop
}
```